# How can recover all data and sites from accidentally delete virtual machine - Microsoft Azure

Tags: virtual-machines, undelete

We have accidentally deleted Virtual Machine from Azure portal. Virtual Machine had about 12 - 15 SQL Server databases and about 10 websites/projected hosted on it.

We are having Biz Spark account. How can we get all the data and website/projects restore. We lost all our projects. Please help me to know the way to get everything restore. Or Is there a way to undelete? We tried the option of selecting from gallery but with no success.

Thanks,
Tariq

Answer (score 2):

When deleting an Azure virtual machine, you can choose if you want to delete only the VM or the attached disks too; if you didn't delete its disks, you will find them in the storage account which the VM was using, and you can use them to create a new VM with the same configuration; but if you deleted the disks together with the VM, then you are out of luck and it's time to bring forth your backups (which you *have*, don't you?).

Comment: Unfortunately, attached disks also deleted. And even worst we were having database backups on save VM. Is there any why by contact Microsoft Azure support team can solve the problem.

Comment: You can try contacting them, maybe they can do something; but officially, you have lost your VM and it can't be recovered.